# Displaying a string in debug mode

Tags: c#, json, string, encoding, asp.net-web-api

I have an object with two string properties. Why does an apostrophe get displayed as `\u0027` when looking at the value of the object in debug, however when you look at the value of the property it shows it as an apostrophe?
See screenshot below:
[image]

Btw I'm receiving this object through a controller's action, would it have something to do with deserializing the object?

EDIT:
I just realised the ToString() method has been overriden and is returning this:

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
```

So why does that method convert an apostrophe to `\u0027t`?

Comment: If you call it "single quote" it is easier to reason why it represented escaped in JSON... I suspect class not shown in the post uses `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` to show value as JSON.

Comment: A single quote is an apostrophe. Why does it make it easier to understand if you give it a different name?

Comment: You edit is a bit strange - should not it be "convert apostrophe to `\u0027`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is valid (`'` and `\u0027` are different representations of the same character for JavaScript/JSON) and you can't have quotes inside quoted string. It is safer to escape both types of quotes for JSON serialization even if it is ok to have opposite quotes in the JSON string "'" and '"'.

Note that JSON.Net version is smarter to not escape all quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("a'b")); // "a\u0027b"
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("a'b")); // "a'b"
```

Comment: are you saying if you had "\"this is a string with 'quotes'\"" those two single quotes would have to be represented as a\u0027b? However if it was "this is a string with 'quotes'" then those single quotes would be fine how they are?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave there are 2 ways to represent string in JavaScript - wrapped in single quotes and double quotes. While only later is valid JSON you sometimes want to use single quotes for strings: so if you have `"with'\" quotes"` and want to use single quote (valid JS) string you have to produce `'with\u0027\" quotes'`, same string in double quotes (valid JSON) can be either `"with'\n quotes"` or `"with\u0027\" quotes"` (as 27 is hex code for apostrophe and there is no special escape sequence as for double quote).

Comment: @Backwards_Dave basically single quote *can* be represented as `\u0027` all the time, but it is optional when JS/JSON string is wrapped with double quotes. Spec can be found at http://json.org/